# How can I do swipe twice in Recyclerview Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want swipe twice in recyclerview like IoS.
First swipe, showing button which is delete button or edit,
And then one more swipe, that item dismiss.

I have done swipe and showing button But I don't know how second swipe.

If you using mail in IoS, more easy understand of second swipe

Here is my Recyclerview swipe helper code

```
private SwipeActionInterface buttonsActions = null;
private boolean swipeBack = false;
private ButtonsState buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.GONE;
private static final float buttonWidth = 200;
private RectF buttonInstance = null;
private RecyclerView.ViewHolder currentItemViewHolder = null;

@Override
public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    int drag_flags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
    int swipe_flags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
    return makeMovementFlags(drag_flags, swipe_flags);
}
public void getButtonGone(boolean flag){
    if(flag){
        buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.GONE;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

    return false;
}


@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
}

public RecyclerviewSwipeHelper(SwipeActionInterface buttonsActions) {
    this.buttonsActions = buttonsActions;
}
/*
@Override
public float getSwipeEscapeVelocity(float defaultValue) {
    return 0.1f * defaultValue;
}

@Override
public float getSwipeVelocityThreshold(float defaultValue) {
    return 5.0f * defaultValue;
}

@Override
public float getSwipeThreshold(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    return swipeTreshold;
}
*/
@Override
public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
    if (swipeBack) {
        swipeBack = buttonShowedState != ButtonsState.GONE;
        return 0;
    }
    return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    if (currentItemViewHolder != null) {
    drawButtons(c, currentItemViewHolder);
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        if (buttonShowedState != ButtonsState.GONE) {
            if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.LEFT_VISIBLE)
                dX = Math.max(dX, buttonWidth);
            if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE)
                dX = Math.min(dX, -buttonWidth);
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        } else {
            setTouchListner(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    }

    if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.GONE) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
    currentItemViewHolder = viewHolder;
   // drawButtons(c, viewHolder);
}

//Button의 모양
private void drawButtons(Canvas c, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    float buttonWidthWithoutPadding = buttonWidth - 10;
    float corners = 5;

    View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
    Paint p = new Paint();


    buttonInstance = null;
    if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {

        RectF leftButton = new RectF(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), itemView.getLeft() + buttonWidthWithoutPadding, itemView.getBottom());
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        c.drawRoundRect(leftButton, corners, corners, p);
        drawText("EDIT", c, leftButton, p);


        buttonInstance = leftButton;
    } else if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
        RectF rightButton = new RectF(itemView.getRight() - buttonWidthWithoutPadding, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        c.drawRoundRect(rightButton, corners, corners, p);
        drawText("DELETE", c, rightButton, p);

        buttonInstance = rightButton;
    }
}

private void drawText(String text, Canvas c, RectF button, Paint p) {
    float textSize = 60;
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setTextSize(textSize);

    float textWidth = p.measureText(text);
    c.drawText(text, button.centerX() - (textWidth / 2), button.centerY() + (textSize / 2), p);
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void setTouchListner(final Canvas c, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final float dX, final float dY, final int actionState, final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            swipeBack = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
            if (swipeBack) {
                if (dX < -buttonWidth) buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE;
                else if (dX > buttonWidth) buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.LEFT_VISIBLE;

                if (buttonShowedState != ButtonsState.GONE) {
                    setTouchDownListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                    setItemsClickable(recyclerView, false);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void setTouchDownListener(final Canvas c, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final float dX, final float dY, final int actionState, final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                setTouchUpListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void setTouchUpListener(final Canvas c, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final float dX, final float dY, final int actionState, final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                RecyclerviewSwipeHelper.super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, 0F, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                        return false;
                    }
                });
                setItemsClickable(recyclerView, true);
                swipeBack = false;
                if (buttonsActions != null && buttonInstance != null && buttonInstance.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.LEFT_VISIBLE) {
                        buttonsActions.onLeftClicked(viewHolder, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    } else if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
                        buttonsActions.onRightClicked(viewHolder, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
                buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.GONE;
                currentItemViewHolder = null;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void setItemsClickable(RecyclerView recyclerView, boolean isClickable) {
    for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); ++i) {
        recyclerView.getChildAt(i).setClickable(isClickable);
    }
}
```

And Part of Main Code

```
 public void setupSwipe(){
    recyclerviewSwipeHelper = new RecyclerviewSwipeHelper(new SwipeActionInterface() {
        @Override
        public void onRightClicked(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            long click_primaryKey = (long)viewHolder.itemView.getTag();
            temporaryStoreData = new TemporaryStoreData();
            final TemporaryStoreData temp = temporaryStoreData.recoverDataMethod(mDatabase, click_primaryKey);
            removeItem(click_primaryKey);
            recyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
            Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "이거고쳐야함", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            ContentValues cv = temporaryStoreData.undoDataContentValue(temp);
                            if(mDatabase.insert(LSSQLContract.LocationTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv) > 0) {
                                recyclerAdapter.swapCursor(databaseSortingQueryMethod(sortingCondition));
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Undo Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onLeftClicked(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "일정에 추가되었습니다", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"취소되었습니다",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    });

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(recyclerviewSwipeHelper);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
        @Override
        public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
            recyclerviewSwipeHelper.onDraw(c);
        }
    });
}
```

Plz help me

Comment: Does the `onSwiped` listener actually detect when you're swiping the recylcer? If so, I would just make an `int` initialized at 0 and when the `onSwiped` is called just `int x++`. After that, make an if statement that `if(x>1){ //dismiss or hide here}`. Hopefully that makes sense, going to be honest; I didn't read all your code.